# C bitwise shift

Tags: c

I suppose sizeof(char) is one byte. Then when I write following code,

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
       char x = 10;

       printf("%d", x<<5);
    }
```

The output is `320`

My question is, if char is one byte long and value is 10, it should be:

```
0000 1010
```

When I shift by 5, shouldn't it become:

```
0100 0001
```

so why is output 320 and not 65?

I am using gcc on Linux and checked that `sizeof(char) = 1`

Comment: Change `void main()` to `int main(void)`, and don't forget the required `#include <stdio.h>`.  Oh, and `sizeof (char) == 1`, by definition (one byte) -- but a byte can be more than 8 bits (though it's going to be exactly 8 bits on any system you're likely to encounter).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C, all intermediates that are smaller than `int` are automatically promoted to `int`.
Therefore, your `char` is being promoted to larger than 8 bits.

So your `0000 1010` is being shifted up by 5 bits to get 320. (nothing is shifted off the top)

If you want to rotate, you need to do two shifts and a mask:

```
unsigned char x = 10;

x = (x << 5) | (x >> 3);
x &= 0xff;

printf("%d", x);
```

It's possible to do it faster using inline assembly or if the compiler supports it, intrinsics.

Comment: Does x &= 0xff do anything useful? The char doesn't every change in size, so and-ing shouldn't do anything, right?

Comment: You're right. In this case it doesn't do anything. I think I was being overly cautious when I wrote this answer. (Possibly to guard against the possibility that `char` could be more than 8 bits.)

Answer (score 1):

Mysticial is right.  If you do

```
char x = 10;
printf("%c", x);
```

It prints "@", which, if you check your ASCII table, is 64.

```
0000 1010 << 5 = 0001 0100 0000
```

You had overflow, but since it was promoted to an int, it just printed the number.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you describe is a rotate, not a shift. `0` is always shifted in on left shifts.

Comment: So is it possible to rotate in C?

Comment: There is no rotate operator, but it is possible to drop to assembly in order to use any rotate opcodes.